# File not found despite showing in ls

Tags: linux, debian

I'm trying to run a script which exists as visible by `ls` but when I try to run it, it says "No such file or directory" What gives?

```
root@rx-texas:/home/7days/linux32#
root@rx-texas:/home/7days/linux32# ls
libstdc++.so.6  steamcmd
root@rx-texas:/home/7days/linux32# ./steamcmd
-bash: ./steamcmd: No such file or directory
root@rx-texas:/home/7days/linux32# less steamcmd
"steamcmd" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?
```

[image: Screenshot]

I'm running 64-bit Debian but the file is linux32 could it be related?

Also here is the output of `ls -la`:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 7days 7days    4096 Apr 22  2013 .
drwxrwxrwx 3 7days 7days    4096 Jan  9 22:44 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 7days 7days 3807525 Apr 22  2013 libstdc++.so.6
-rwxrwxrwx 1 7days 7days 5642610 Feb  5  2013 steamcmd
```

output of `ldd steamcmd`:

```
not a dynamic executable
```

Comment: Please post the output of  `ldd steamcmd`.

Comment: @MarkWagner updated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm running 64-bit debian but the file is linux32 could it be related?

It's not only related, but is the direct cause of the error.

When you try to run 32-bit executable on a 64-bit system without support for 32-bit runtime installed, this misleading error is displayed. It is not the `./steamcmd` that is missing, but its loader.

For a detailed explanation see the answer under [Getting "Not found" message when running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13391/133107) on Unix.SE.

The suggested solution for Debian is to install multi-architecture support with:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get update
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the solution. For reference, when I ran this command, it worked: `dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

Check the first line of the script. If you are using a "#!" to reference an executable (e.g. a shell), make SURE the referenced file is: present and accessible by the userid attempting to run steamcmd.

E.g. if you have:

"#!/bin/bash"

On the first line, /bin/bash needs to be present. Looks like you're root, so access shouldn't be a problem. Make sure you don't have any extra spaces in the path to the file or unprintable characters at the end of the line.

Comment: steamcmd is a binary file

Comment: I see the output from 'less' but in your original post you said "I'm trying to run a script...". Mark's ldd question is good. What does: "file steamcmd" report?

Comment: I have a script that calls that file and that error is shown. Here is output of file: `steamcmd: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.34, BuildID[sha1]=17188c02dec11be2af104afd625f39a2c89b54c7, not stripped`

Comment: Are you sure the script calling steamcmd is not the problem? I.e. does that script fail immediately with the same error? Or do you have other output from the script indicating it is running properly up to the steamcmd call?